# Sharepoint 2016 -Send to , Manage and go to source button are desabled

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

When I select some folder in SharePoint 2016 to move for another list the icons send to, manage copies and go to source in ribbon files are disabled.

Comment: Which permissions do you have on the list?

Comment: full control, this issue is only in sharepoint 2016, 2013 sharepoint works well

Answer (score 0):

**Unfrothuantly,** the "`Send to`" is not working with

- Folders.
- Multiple documents.

It's work only with **single** documents.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, Send to, Manage Copies and Go To Source in ribbon are disabled for a folder.

[image]

Refer to the following article about how to copy, move, and clone files and folders in SharePoint - Exploring All Options:

https://truapps.portalfront.com/how-to-copy-and-move-files-between-sharepoint-document-libraries-and-folders.html

Comment: This issue is only in sharepoint 2016, 2013 sharepoint works well